# ConcurentCollection ordering items by key and value whilst updating value atomically

Tags: java, concurrency, set

I am trying to have a collection that can sort entrys by both key and values but allows the value to be updated/incremented atomically. You can only order on keys with the ConcurrentHashMap so I tried using a ConcurrentSkipListSet but it does not support putifabsent and replace(key,oldvalue,newvalue) like ConcurrentHashMap does so I'm not quite sure how to update/icrement the value atomically with the set collections.

heres my comparator I was using for the ConcurrentSkipListSet

It should order on the first string, then on the value then on the second string

```
Comparator<Fun.Tuple3<String,String,Integer>> c = new Comparator<Fun.Tuple3<String,String,Integer>>() {

 @Override
 public int compare(Tuple3<String, String, Integer> o1, Tuple3<String, String, Integer> o2) {
 if(o1.a.compareTo(o2.a) == 0){
 if(Integer.compare(o1.c,o2.c)==0){
 return o1.b.compareTo(o2.b);
 }
 return Integer.compare(o1.c,o2.c);
 }
 return o1.a.compareTo(o2.a);
 }
 };
```

Unfortunately I can not combine the two Strings together to form a single key because I need to perform a query such as "match first string, any second string, any value" and have the results ordered by the comparator above which I can do with the Set. However If I need to update a tuple I would first need to get the old value using

```
OldValue = Set.ceiling(new Fun.Tuple3<>(String,String,Integer.MinValue))
```

then remove the element from the set and then increment the integer by 1 and add it to the set again. The problem is that between the Set.ceiling, remomve and add calls the value could have been added/removed/changed by another thread.

without a method like >

```
AtomicIncrement(Tuple3 tuple3){
 oldValue = Set.ceiling(tuple3)
 while(true){
   if(set.replace(oldValue,newValue)) return;
 }
}
```

I dont see how I can update the value safely.

Comment: There is _no_ `Set` implementation that will continue to work if you change the order of the elements within the `Set`, e.g. with a `Comparator`.  Without inventing a complete data structure from scratch, the only real alternative I can think of is to use a synchronized `TreeSet` and to remove the old value and add the new in a synchronized block, when you want to update.

Comment: (To be clear, using a synchronized `TreeSet` would make this work, but there's certainly no built-in data structure -- possibly not any data structure at all -- that will let you atomically replace an element like you're trying to do, without blocking at all.)